# Relative Kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, inertial-frames, relative-motion

Let velocities of two bodies $m_1$ and $m_2$ be $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively. So can we write **relative kinetic energy** of $m_1$ with respect to $m_2$ =
$$\frac {1}{2} m_1 (v_1-v_2)^2$$

Comment: 2 objects can only have 1 velocity relative to each other.

Comment: Do you mean v1 and v2 relative to a third frame of reference?

Comment: I am talking about relative velocity of one body with respect to other not the third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be the relative kinetic energy, assuming you meant to write $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ as *vectors*.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy of relative velocity of one object moving with speed $v_1$ to other with $v_2$ is given by:

$$E_K= \frac {1}{2}m_1 |(\mathbf v_1- \mathbf v_2)|^2$$.

Comment: *Whereas what you state is the difference in the kinetic energy of the two objects.* That would be $\frac12 m(v_1^2-v_2^2)$, which is *not* what the OP stated.

Comment: @G.Smith yes you are right. I misread the question as it wasn't in mathjax,